# performSelectorInBackground: crashed immediately on mac os x 10.6.3

Tags: macos, cocoa, crash-reports, performselector

I'm trying to test out my Mac os App, it worked well on 10.8 however when I start testing it on mac 10.6.3 (iatkos s3) I got some problem.

First, I have to use a separate computer to install 10.6.3, as my macbook air won't allow me to install 10.6.3 (hardware is newer than the software). What I did was, in xcode I run it, get the .app file, put it to my 10.6.3 application folder then run it.

I put some trace log there and here is my code:

```
- (void) startMethodInBackground: (id) sender {
    NSLog(@"line 101"); //this shows
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(myOtherMethod:) withObject:sender];
    NSLog(@"line 102"); //not showing
}

- (void) myOtherMethod: (id) sender {
    NSLog(@"line 201"); //not showing 
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"line 202"); //again not showing
        @synchronized (self) {
            NSLog(@"line 203"); //not showing
            ... ...
        }
    }
}



Version:         1.0 (1)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1126]

Date/Time:       2013-02-28 16:53:10.668 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.3 (10D573)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  2
... (too long so I trimmed it)
...
    Thread 2 Crashed:
0   ???                             000000000000000000 0 + 0
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff814e4ead __NSThread__main__ + 1429
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff86db38b6 _pthread_start + 331
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x00007fff86db3769 thread_start + 13

Thread 2 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000000  rbx: 0x0000000100863400  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x00000001001417b0
  rdi: 0x00000001001417b0  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000100480c90  rsp: 0x0000000100480b08
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000100201530  r10: 0x0000000100210870  r11: 0x0000000100002120
  r12: 0x00007fff5fbfe800  r13: 0x0000000000001b07  r14: 0x00007fff814e4918  r15: 0x0000000102e0ec20
  rip: 0x0000000000000000  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x0000000000000000
```

as you can see in my code, as soon as I call myOtherMethod: using performSelectorInBackground:, it crashed!!

so my questions are:

1. any reason why calling performSelectorInBackground crashed?? I checked the performSelectorInBackground method and it should work fine on 10.6 (apple document says 10.5 or later), so I really have to what happened!!!
2. the crash report really makes no sense to me, so in real life how can you debug with such report? in xcode, if there is any problem, it will crash and will tell me which method caused the problem and what was the problem, but as you can see, the crash report didn't tell me much!

Any help is appreciated.
Josh

Comment: Is it possible your object is being deallocated?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a corrupt stack.

Are you perhaps allocating huge amounts of memory in `myOtherMethod`, like a big C array? What happens when you call `myOtherMethod` on the main thread?

Comment: it has nothing to do with the memory allocation. I created a dummy app, used performSelectorsInBackground: to call a dummy method, inside this dummy method, I had @ autoreleasepool then @ synchronized (self) and nothing else but some simple traces. If I take out @ synchronized, it won't crash, if I put @synchronized, it crashed. The reason why I used synchronized is, I want to make sure no multiple threads run myOtherMethod at the same time, if thread 1 is running myOtherMethod, thread 2 should wait until thread 1 is finished. But why it synchronized crashed on 10.6 but not 10.8????